Adjust console width to print the whole Pandas dataframe
When printing to the console in Python I get output like:
                   Körpergrösse (cm)  ...  Motivation (1-10) 
Körpergrösse (cm)           1.000000  ...           0.226576 
Schuhgrösse                 0.710021  ...           0.096692 
Alter (Jahre)              -0.206736  ...           0.203746 
Motivation (1-10)           0.226576  ...           1.000000
    
[4 rows x 4 columns]

This is a pity because in my console there is more than enough space to print a lot more.
(In this example the whole 4 x 4 correlation matrix..)

How can I make my console print the 'whole thing'? For example, by adjusting the console width? Or if that's not possible by doing some workaround before/while printing?

Assuming you are using pandas you can use these settings:
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)

print(df)

the last option is to ensure it fits the console width
